# Safari text-shadow duplicates text

Tags: css, safari

I have a weird problem, where my font gets displayed 2 times below eachother when using text-shadow in safari. (Used for h2 tags)

I tried the solutions of some other posts, like swapping the color as first argument and then the dimensions, but that didnt help.

This is my CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-family: "sauna-bold", sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
}
```

Here is an Screenshoot on how my text is displayed:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use prefix CSS to make your styles compatible with the browsers?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what u mean by that.
You mean those -moz.. and similar stylings?
How would I do that here?

Comment: That's fine. I added in the answer below a link that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try css prefix. which is responsible to make your style compatible with the browser. here's more detail for it as well [prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

```
  h2 {
      -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
      -moz-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
      -ms-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
      -o-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
   }
```

Comment: OK I tried that, but it doesn't work either.  
When I remove font-family from the H2, I get my text-shadow, but not with the needed font :/  
Its weird since it works in any other Browser just fine.  
Do you have any other idea for that?

Comment: Actually when I remove this CSS from my body the text-shadow works, but then like 50% of my text is missing.
-webkit-text-stroke-width: thin;

Comment: @GrimclawDraven Will browsers behave differently, especially in CSS. I really don't know more about your case. I thought by using the prefix. it might help you.